# Is it possible to assign to 2 different ranges of a numpy array (arr[a:b , c:d]) in one go?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray

I have this line from [Jeff Heatons github](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/04dc6e368f15d7643c31745cae232ba31810ca99/t81_558_class_07_2_Keras_gan.ipynb):

```
image_array[r:r+GENERATE_SQUARE,c:c+GENERATE_SQUARE] = generated_images[image_count] * 255
```

Trying to understand this by testing it with simple data:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(x[1:4, 6:8])
```

I get an error:
**IndexError: Too many indices for array**

But Jeff's code works. What's going on here?

Comment: One `a:b` per dimension.  Your `x` is 1d, so only 1 slice.

Comment: @hpaulj That makes sense, you should make it an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array given in the example has 2 dimensions. It is not assigning to two multiple ranges in a single go but it's an assignment to a subset of a 2-dimensional array.

To reproduce it, consider following snippet:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5,6]])
>>> x.ndim
>>> 2 # 2 dimensional array
>>> x[0:1, 0:1] = 2 # This means 1st element of 1st dim and 1st element of 2nd dim.
>>> x
>>> array([[2, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]])
```

Refer this for slicing of n-dimensional arrays in `numpy`. Hope this helps!